# can't find search statistics in geonetwork

Tags: geonetwork

I'm using Geonetwork and I need to show search statistics. In admin console, I went to "statistics & statut" but the problem is, I can't find "search statistics" inside.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v3.4.0 GeoNetwork uses Elasticsearch & Kibana to store and show the catalog statistics. You need to set up them and configue GN to use your instances.
You can find some documentation [here](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/3.4.x/es) and [here](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/3.4.x/es/es-dashboards).

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJl9stYMsG0&t=12s) you can view the new module in action.